# Is caching in browser automatic?

Tags: http, caching

I have a JavaScript app that sends requests to REST API, the responses from server have cache headers (like ETag, cache-control, expires). Is caching of responses in browser automatic, or the app must implement some sort of mechanism to save the data?

Comment: You could check yourself by using the network inspector on chrome/firefox. (spoiler: yes; browsers will cache ajax calls if the headers are set up properly)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230998/cant-the-browser-just-use-its-cache-from-prior-ajax-calls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An AJAX request is no different from a normal request - it's a GET/POST/HEAD/whatever request being sent by the browser, and it is handled as such. This is confirmed [here](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/08/07/ajax-caching-two-important-facts/):

> The HTTP and Cache sub-systems of modern browsers are at a much lower level than Ajax’s XMLHttpRequest object. At this level, the browser doesn’t know or care about Ajax requests. It simply obeys the normal HTTP caching rules based on the response headers returned from the server.

As per [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), caches can also be invalidated in at least one usual way (appending a query string):

> **cache** (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

So in short, given the same headers, AJAX responses are cached the same way as other requests.

Answer (score 2):

Browser handles automatically cache of resources. What you seem to be asking about is the actuall response from the server.

You will need to set that up yourself in your application. You can do so both on front-end and backend.

Most of JS frameworks have cache control implemented, for example:

**jQuery**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

**AngularJS**

```
$http.defaults.cache = false;
```

etc.

On backend it really depends on what language you using, what server engine etc.

Checkout Memcached for example
http://memcached.org/

As with anything with web development there are odd things here and there, for example **some IE versions are automatically chaching requests** and you have to add unique id to the url to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started :

> Note 2: If you do not set header Cache-Control: no-cache the browser will cache the response and never re-submit the request, making debugging "challenging." You can also append an always-diferent aditional GET parameter, like the timestamp or a random number (see bypassing the cache)

Answer (score 0):

Browser should handle the cache automatically.
Check this article, there's only clear cache method for javascript. 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData

Comment: Is it really a cache of HTTP response ? It seems to me that it is a cache for web site resource

Comment: It depends. Almost every modern browser will cache .js, .css and images by default. Within those types of files, there are options that ask the browser to not cache. On the user end, there are usually settings to not cache anything.

Comment: I am not talking about caching of resources, but about caching data that comes for rest api in json.

Answer (score 0):

If the server sends the response with any of cache headers browsers should respect it. there is no difference between resources or ajax requests.

also you can specify cache headers in your ajax calls to make it not use caches and fetch the whole response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers support browser caching because of the cache and expire headers

http://www.arlocarreon.com/blog/http/http-requests-and-your-browsers-cache/

```
There are 2 apects of an HTTP request that can qualify it for being cached:  
  - Specifc HTTP cache and expire headers  
  - A unique URL
```

Interesting read:

http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/