# Is holding data on the browser (as a JS array) a bad thing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, performance

Here is my code:

```js
var back_arr    = [],
    forward_arr = [],
    i = 1;
$('button').on('click', function(){
  var new_value = $('input').val(),
      old_value = $('.content').html();
  i = i + 1;
  $('.content').html("#" + i + " - " + new_value);
  back_arr.push(old_value);
  
  back();
  forward_arr = [];
  forward();
})

function back(){
  if ( back_arr.length > 0 ){
    $('.back').show();
  } else {
    $('.back').hide();
  }
}

function forward(){
  if ( forward_arr.length > 0 ){
    $('.forward').show();
  } else {
    $('.forward').hide();
  }
}

$('.back').on('click', function(){
  var current_value = $('.content').html();
  forward_arr.push(current_value);
  $('.content').html(back_arr.pop());
  back();
  forward();
})

$('.forward').on('click', function(){
  var current_value = $('.content').html();
  back_arr.push(current_value);
  $('.content').html(forward_arr.pop());
  back();
  forward();
})
```

```css
.content{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.back,.forward{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<button>add</button>
<br /><br />
<div class="content">
  #1 - something
</div>
<br /><br />
<a class="back" href="#">back</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="forward" href="#">forward</a>
```

As you see, I've tried to implement  *back* and *forward* buttons. As you see, I'm storing the content as HTML *(in reality it may be much more larger than what's in the example above)* into a JS array. Is doing that a bad idea?

Actually I'm trying to avoid sending duplicate ajax requests per page life cycle. Is there anyone who suggests using localStorage (or sessionStorage) to keep data instead of a JS array? Also is there any thing I can do to make my code more optimized?

Comment: This is premature optimization. Don't worry about it unless you run into problems.

Comment: In reality, all forms of code hold on to some form of data somewhere.

Comment: @JJJ Well I haven't implemented it in my real code yet .. I want to know, if I'll be faced with problem, then doing that the other way (using local storage instead)

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I don't get your point sadly ...! I don't know English very well, may you please rephrase your sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Using a JS Array to store data means that as soon as the user refreshes the page, he/she will lose all that data. If you are ok with that, I don't see any problem.

Using localStorage or something like https://github.com/localForage/localForage will help you maintain data. So even if the user refreshes the page, data it's still there.

It really depends what do you have to store.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a good answer because it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you are asking if network optimization or caching is best achieved by something like your code, the answer is a definite no. Less so the storage part and more so trying to reinvent the wheel with the back and forward functions, which the browser already handles. You're sure to miss something, and there are [already libraries that handle this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history). In terms of caching the data from an ajax request, this is already handled by the HTTP specification, in which the server can give an expiration for the data and the browser will continue to use the cached data until it expires. If you want to know more about ajax caching, there are already [answers on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230998/cant-the-browser-just-use-its-cache-from-prior-ajax-calls).